# Only data of first element appears in modal-form Angular ngFor

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ngfor

I used ngFor to generate the data i created and i want the data inside the modal form to change for each element but instead when i click on any element only the data of the first element in the page appears how can i change this

here is my code :

```
<div class="row">        
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-3" *ngFor="let prop of filteredProperties | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 12, currentPage: p }">   
                <div class="single-property">
                    <div class="" id="mc_embed_signup">

                        <form target="_blank" novalidate="true" action="https://spondonit.us12.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=1462626880ade1ac87bd9c93a&amp;id=92a4423d01" method="get" class="form-inline">
            
                        <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel3" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                   
                                  <div class="modal-content">
                                    
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel3">Unit Details</h5>
                                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                      </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <br>
                                        <p>Project : {{prop.project}} <br>
                                            Unit Name : {{prop.unit_name}} <br>
                                           Unit Usage :  {{prop.unit_usage}} <br>
                                           Country : {{prop.country}} <br>
                                           Unit for : {{prop.unit_for}} <br>
                                           Finishing : {{prop.finishing}} <br>
                                           Property type : {{prop.property_type}} <br>
                                           City : {{prop.city}} <br>
                                           District: {{prop.district}} <br>
                                           Min. Area: {{prop.min_area}} <br>
                                           Starting Price: {{prop.starting_price}}<br> <br>
                                           <img style="height: 150px; width: 250px;" src= {{prop.img}}>
                                             </p>
                                          
                                            <div class="alert-msg">
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                  
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                                <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;">
                                    <input name="b_36c4fd991d266f23781ded980_aefe40901a" tabindex="-1" value="" type="text">
                                </div>
                        </div>      
                        <div class="info"></div>
                        </form>
                </div>
                    <div class="images">
                        <img style="height: 250px; width: 350px;" class="content-image img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src= {{prop.img}} alt="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal3">
                        <span style="margin-top: 0px; color:black;background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);"><br>{{prop.property_type}} <br><br><br> {{prop.developer}} <br><br><br> {{prop.district}} <br></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
</div>
```

Comment: Would appreaciate a help cause i'm still stuck there

Comment: I tried using [attr.id]="prop" and [attr.data-target]="'#'prop" and it didn't work